Gmsh getElementsByType does not return all the elements in Python API
I was trying to use the function getElementsByType in Python to return all the triangular elements over a rectangle domain (simply the t1.py example). However, there are 796 trangles in the mesh, the getElementsByType function can only return 726 elements, the element with tag from 1 to 70 have not shown up.
import gmsh
import sys
import numpy as np

gmsh.initialize()

gmsh.model.add("t1")
lc = 1e-2

gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(0, 0, 0, lc, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(.1, 0, 0, lc, 2)
gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(.1, .3, 0, lc, 3)
p4 = gmsh.model.geo.addPoint(0, .3, 0, lc)

gmsh.model.geo.addLine(1, 2, 1)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(3, 2, 2)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(3, p4, 3)
gmsh.model.geo.addLine(4, 1, p4)

gmsh.model.geo.addCurveLoop([4, 1, -2, 3], 1)

gmsh.model.geo.addPlaneSurface([1], 1)

gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()

gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(1, [1, 2, 4], 5)
gmsh.model.addPhysicalGroup(2, [1], name="My surface")

gmsh.model.mesh.generate(2)

gmsh.write("t1.msh")
gmsh.open("t1.msh")

dim = -1
tag = -1
# we print the coordinates of nodes
nodeTags, coords, paraCoord = gmsh.model.mesh.getNodes(dim, tag)
coords = coords.reshape(-1,3)
xy = coords.reshape(-1,3)
for Tag, xy_e in zip(nodeTags, xy):
    print(f"Node #{Tag} is at {xy_e}")

defined_element_type = gmsh.model.mesh.getElementTypes()
print(defined_element_type)

eletype = 2
tag = -1
eleTags, nodeTags = gmsh.model.mesh.getElementsByType(eletype, tag)
nodeTags = nodeTags.reshape(-1,3)

nodesEachEle = []
for Tag, nodes in zip(eleTags, nodeTags):
    print(f"Element #{Tag} has nodes {nodes}")
    nodesEachEle.append(nodes)
#if '-nopopup' not in sys.argv:
    #gmsh.fltk.run()

gmsh.finalize()

Someone kindly help me to find out the reason and solution for this problem? Many thanks in advance!
